# Credits without completing all missions?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

This question contains a bit of a spoiler, so if you haven't yet seen the credits read no further.

I just got the credits in the game, completing the mission where you take out the three targets with the three guys.

But, when I go to the start menu it tells me I've only completed like 38/67 missions? What else is included in this count? I presume the "?" missions aren't.

Comment: Yes all together there is 67 "?" missions which are the main story missions and the 67 count for only "?" missions. If you finished the game then you should have 67. It could be a graphical bug you have.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the stranger missions which show on the map as a question mark. Are they included in the 67?

Comment: No they aren't they go under there own category. If you go into menu and I think 100% completion, if shows you a table of all the mission category and how many you done in each category. I think there is 21 strangers missions.

Answer (score 3):

There are several missions that are included in the 67, that are not required to complete the Big Score.  The ones I know for sure are Lester's assassination missions.

Comment: @AndrewC: Then please mark this answer as the correct answer.

Comment: @DarkDecipio This is only a partial answer so shouldn't be accepted in this form.  Lester does not give you 29 missions and the question asks what else is included :)

Comment: @Archer: Hm. True. It should be a Community Wiki answer...

Answer (score 0):

There are 69 story missions (67 if you're not counting the two missions you won't choose at the ending mission), but I really doubt you can finish the story with only 38 missions done.

So I guess 38 is a bug or another count, maybe the missions where you got the gold medal?

For information, there are 20 Strangers & Freaks missions to do according to the Social Club, but this number goes up to 58 if you count every sub-mission for each of these characters missions. For example, Tonya will give you 5 similar towing missions to Franklin (Pulling favors)